# Show array values in D3.js html tooltip

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I'm trying to show some data from my json file on D3 tooltip.
I could show almost all the data, I just can't display all the objects of the array, it just shows me the last object of the array.

I made up this simple example to be easier to show you whats happening. 
I'm just listing name and dependencies in my tooltip.

**My tooltip**

```
var myTollTip = d3.select(".container")
    .append("div")
    .attr("class", "mytooltip")
    .style("opacity", "0")
    .style("display", "none");
```

**Behaviour**

```
node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 8)
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return color(d.name);
    })

    .on("dblclick", function(d){
        d3.select(this)
            .transition()
            .duration(500)
            .style("cursor", "pointer")
            .attr("width", 60)
            myTollTip
              .transition()  //Opacity transition when the tooltip appears
              .duration(500)
              .style("opacity", "1")                           
              .style("display", "table-cell")  //The tooltip appears
              .style("vertical-align", "top");
            i=0;
            while (i<2){
                myTollTip
                    .html("<p>Name: " + d.name + "</p><p>" + d.dependencies[i].url + "</p>");
                i++;
            } 
    })
```

**json data**

```
    {
      "nodes":[
        {
          "name": "name1",
          "dependencies": [
            {
              "url": "examlple.com"
            },
            {
              "url": "google.com"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "name": "name2",
          "dependencies": [
            {
              "url": "yahoo.com"
            },
            {
              "url": "google.com"
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "links":[
      ]
    }
```

**Result (if I double click in the first node):**

Name: name1
google.com

**My goal (if I double click in the first node):**

Name: name1
exmaple.com
google.com

**My conclusions**

Well to display the objects of an array I should need to create a loop as I did. But as the loop is applying to the d3 .html , its overriding the html 2 times and of course it shows the last data.

**My question**

How can I have a loop just for my array inside the d3 .html? 
or
There is another way to show array objects in d3 tooltip?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a string and, on each iteration, add the desired data to the string:

```
    var myString = "";
    var i = 0;
    while(i<2){
       myString = myString + ("<p>" + d.dependencies[i].url + "</p>");
       i++;
    }
    myTollTip.style("opacity", "1")                           
       .style("display", "table-cell")  
       .style("vertical-align", "top")
       .html("<p>Name: " + d.name + "</p>" + myString);
```

Check this fiddle. I made 2 circles, each one representing one node. The tooltip appears when you click on the circle: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/gtvcbosh/2/